# Get [offline] off our lines

Tags: discussion, tags

Do we really need the [offline](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offline) tag?

I think its a meta-tag and should be burniated.

It can't stand as the only tag on a question and I can't see anybody subscribing to it (or are there any offline experts?) or ignoring it.

So, while it is of course a valid restriction for some software, I think its a bad tag for categorizing questions.

Also, it does mean different things to different people (e.G. I found [a question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/17636/94) with: "By offline I mean: no server involved").

Comment: "are there any offline experts?" – definitely. But they are all offline, so they can't subscribe #D

Comment: Related: [Dealing with obvious tags](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1147/60)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can it stand as the only tag? Probably not — because we want a platform tag and a domain tag on most questions. We have other tags that can't be used on their own, such as [gratis](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gratis) and [open-source](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source). A tag that can't be used on its own is a red flag, but it doesn't automatically invalidate the tag.

Are there [offline](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offline) domain experts? Kinda. Not, I think, whole-domain experts, but experts in offline use of mobile platforms (so [android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android) [offline](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offline) experts, [ios](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios) [offline](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offline) experts, etc.), for example people who spend a lot of time using their phone or tablet in airplanes.

Can I imagine someone subscribing to [offline](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offline)? Yes — people who are interested in using their mobile platform offline, and who might combine this with ignoring tags for the mobile platforms they don't use. [offline](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offline) in fact has one follower.

Can I imagine someone ignoring [offline](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offline)? No, I don't see why.

Is [offline](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offline) useful in a search? Yes, definitely. It's useful whenever you're looking for something that typically requires access to a server, such as maps and directions, editing data stored on a server, etc.

Is [offline](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offline) ambiguous? This is really what makes or break a tag. Yes, [offline](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offline) is somewhat ambiguous — we have people using it for anything that's offline (but it is not useful to tag every Windows/OSX/Linux question that way), whereas it should really be used only in cases where the offlineness is a non-obvious characteristic. But it isn't outright bad if [offline](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offline) is used in these obvious cases — the tag isn't ambiguous as in having multiple meanings, only as in being overused. To give an example of a similar problem, we have the same kind of misuse on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) where distribution tags should only be used for problems that are specific to a distribution, but people tend to use them to mean “I'm running <distribution>”. That does not by any means invalidate the usefulness of these tags, we wouldn't want to remove them. We just remove the tag when it's used but not warranted.

Is [offline](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offline) a meta tag, i.e. a tag that characterizes the way the question is asked rather than what the question is about? No.

Conclusion: [offline](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offline) is a useful categorization, useful enough that we need a tag for it — if not “offline” then some other, less discoverable name. It gets some misuse but at a manageable level. Let's keep it.